# Why is a password-protected root account a security issue in Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

just asking this out of curiosity. i set up a free EC2 instance last night and as i was ssh-ing around the file system, i realized the root password hadn't been set, and that there was no `sudo` password. this is shocking to me, as i'm used to always setting a root/`sudo` password during the installation or post-install setup phase of any linux distribution.

amazon's documentation has [an article on the topic](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-change-root-linux/), where they discourage users from setting a root password at all:

> For security purposes, it's a best practice to avoid root passwords.

why is an unsecured root account a "best practice?" and additionally, when would i want to use a temporary root password to perform a task as the article suggests?

Comment: A root account without a password is **not** unsecured. It's **inaccessible** via a login prompt (be that local or via ssh).

Answer (score 4):

That quote is saying that it is bad practice to login as the `root` user. Elevated access should always be obtained via `sudo`.

See: [Why is it bad to log in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16178)

To see how to grant `sudo` permissions, see: [How does Amazon ec2-user get its sudo rights](https://serverfault.com/q/599357)